# How can I run sinatra inside existing rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra

I've got a rails application it contains web interface and api.

I want to rewrite api using sinatra. I want all requests to "/api/..." to be handled by sinatra and ignored by rails.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possibile. See [mount](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base/mount). With that you can do something like:

```
FooApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'welcome#index'
  mount FooAppApi => "/api" 
end
```